# List of bounties with no deadlines

Tags: discussion, bounty

I like [the list of "bounties with no deadline](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1091/5581) (which is based on Puzzling and Code Golf equivalents) on Literature, so I am stealing it with attribution; this is almost completely copied and pasted from the other site.

---

**This is a list of unofficial, deadline-less (hence not searchable) bounties offered by users on various challenges on the main site.**

The list need not be limited to questions that already have an answer. You can offer bounties both for your own questions and for other people's questions.

**Disclaimer**: There is no guarantee that the user will award the bounty for you in case you fulfil its requirement. Especially if the user isn't an active member anymore. The only guarantee is their written word.

---

**Guidelines for updating**

- To add a bounty, create an answer that contains a link to the question that needs a (better) answer and the bounty you are willing to award.

  - Answers can be sorted to see which bounties are newest.
  - Please comment on answers if you notice that there’s been a good answer to the question in question for a while that the bountier apparently hasn’t seen.
- If a bounty is awarded, delete the *meta* answer.

Comment: If I have multiple questions I'm willing to offer a bounty for, should I create multiple answers?

Comment: @Thunderforge - That would seem sensible.

Answer (score 6):

I am offering a bounty of 50 reputation on this currently unanswered question

> [Spambot becomes self aware but every attempt to contact gets filtered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/192165/102999)

Answer (score 5):

I am offering 100 bounty on my currently unanswered question in [the-darkest-minds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-darkest-minds).

> https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193227/why-were-reds-considered-more-dangerous-than-oranges

Comment: 50 or 100? Which is it? Or is it like a lottery....

Comment: @Valorum depending on how well fleshed out the answer is

Comment: Well, you won't really have a choice - since you've already spent 50 on a bounty a while back, bountying the same question again will cost you 100 minimum (see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty))

Comment: @Jenayah well then 100 it is!

Answer (score 4):

I am offering a bounty of 100 for any information about how Jack Kirby's concept work on *Lord of Light* may have influenced his later work:

> [Was Jack Kirby's later comic book art influenced by his work on concept art for Lord of Light?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174609/was-jack-kirbys-later-comic-book-art-influenced-by-his-work-on-concept-art-for)

Answer (score 4):

I am offering 50 bounty to the following question (which is not an identification question!) about a [marvel-2099](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-2099) comic series:

> [How old was Miguel O'Hara when he became Spider-Man 2099?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190541/13217)

Answer (score 4):

I'm offering a 250 reputation bounty for a satisfactory answer to this [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) question:

> [Is there a canon interpretation of who the five are in the Prophecy of the Five from the KOTOR Comics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/207527/13217)

Comment: You have a whole bunch of answers here, meaning a lot of scrolling to get through everything. I wonder if it would make more sense to put all your bounty offers into one answer (and edit to strikethrough or remove parts of the answer if the bounty is awarded), to be "the Thunderforge offer list" rather than many different offers in different posts?

Answer (score 4):

I am offering a bounty of 50 or more reputation on this [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question, due to the insane amount of detail.

> [A small group of children accidentally time-traveling to the future and learning about everyday life in an utopistic future society](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/199718/102999)

Answer (score 3):

I am offering 100 bounty to the following question about Frank Herbert’s [dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune) series:

> [What age would an off-worlder start taking the spice Melange?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/206886/13217)

I previously put a bounty on it, but it expired with no new answers. I am looking for an answer that relies on original sources (book quotes, author statements, etc), *not* a wiki.

Answer (score 3):

I am offering a bounty of 100-200 each for answers to the following questions:

- [Short story where Earth was entirely paved over](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205946/short-story-where-earth-was-entirely-paved-over)
- [Aliens have seeded a world with needlers that inject a RNA-type virus into their users to program them with xenophobia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232297/aliens-have-seeded-a-world-with-needlers-that-inject-a-rna-type-virus-into-their)
- [Aliens run a BBS to conduct anthropological investigation of Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237678/aliens-run-a-bbs-to-conduct-anthropological-investigation-of-earth)

Answer (score 2):

I am offering a bounty of 50 or more reputation on this currently unanswered question

> [Short story about dogs and humans in the far future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/163335/102999)

Answer (score 2):

I am offering up a 500 rep bounty on the following [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions:

> [Webcomic following a boy who's inhabited by a vengeful ghost who's after the men who killed her](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/webcomic-following-a-boy-whos-inhabited-by-a-vengeful-ghost-whos-after-the-men)

> [Children's book about a man and a woman (a boy and a girl?) on a mountain with a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144130/childrens-book-about-a-man-and-a-woman-a-boy-and-a-girl-on-a-mountain-with-a)

> [Christian conversion X-men fanfic involving Wolfsbane and Wolverine in Limbo, autumnal theme](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91814/christian-conversion-x-men-fanfic-involving-wolfsbane-and-wolverine-in-limbo-au)

Comment: You have a whole bunch of answers here, meaning a lot of scrolling to get through everything. I wonder if it would make more sense to put all your bounty offers into one answer (and edit to strikethrough or remove parts of the answer if the bounty is awarded), to be "the FuzzyBoots offer list" rather than many different offers in different posts?

Comment: Good point. It is done.

Answer (score 2):

I am offering a 100 rep bounty on this [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)  question:

> [Old Mickey Mouse comic with scifi elements](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/old-mickey-mouse-comic-with-scifi-elements)

Answer (score 1):

I am offering bounties of +100 for the identification of each of the items listed below—and +200 for locating a watchable/playable version of each.

> <s>[Educational film where all the bright colours were kidnapped by the evil gray monster](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146930/looking-for-educational-film-about-sentient-colors)</s>  *This one has been identified.*
>
> [Seeking a game like Hunt the Wumpus but with graphics, RPG elements, and a balrog](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176614/seeking-a-game-like-hunt-the-wumpus-but-with-graphics-rpg-elements-and-a-balro)
>
> [Seeking humorous film, parodying modern architecture in a near-future setting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179389/seeking-humorous-film-parodying-modern-architecture-in-a-near-future-setting)
>
> [What movie or television show contains a short clip of Radagast the Brown?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118039/what-movie-or-television-show-contains-a-short-clip-of-radagast-the-brown)

Comment: You can make these all separate so you get more attention for each one, others are doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I am offering a 100-200 bounty, or more (depending how good the answer is) for a logical answer to [Do Goblins consider all money ever made theirs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174706/do-goblins-consider-all-money-ever-made-theirs). I, and I alone, will decide if the answer makes sense for my purposes. I do not like the current answers.

If a canon answer is provided - from the books or a JKR quote - a minimum of 250 will be given (more for an obscure quote or better answer.)

This is a [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) question, not a story ID question, so it should be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I am offering a 250 rep bounty for anyone who finds a JK Rowling quote for this.

> **[Is there an official way to refer to communicating by putting your head in the fire?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246417/is-there-an-official-way-to-refer-to-communicating-by-putting-your-head-in-the-f)**

---

I am offering a 300 rep bounty to anyone who can find this fake Harry Potter 7 ebook that was going around the internets in 2007.

> **[Where can I find this fake seventh Harry Potter book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251828/where-can-i-find-this-fake-seventh-harry-potter-book)**

---

<s>I am offering a 250 rep bounty for anyone who can find a source of this image.</s>

> **[What is the source of this lighting bolt shaped wand movement for Avada Kedavra?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250043/what-is-the-source-of-this-lighting-bolt-shaped-wand-movement-for-avada-kedavra)**

**Answered and bountied**

---

<s>I am offering a 300 rep bounty for a successful retrieval of this JKR content</s>

> **[What was the original version of this FAQ answer on JK Rowling's website?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193704/what-was-the-original-version-of-this-faq-answer-on-jk-rowlings-website)**

**Answered and bountied.**

---

<s>I am offering a 300 rep bounty for a successful retrieval of this JKR content</s>

> **[What was the original version of this post on JK Rowling's website?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229836/what-was-the-original-version-of-this-post-on-jk-rowlings-website)**

**Bounty has been given to someone who reasonably proved that there was no additional content.** (But I'll offer a 500 rep bounty if you still find it.)